# Linux CLI into Android

Tags: android

I was wondering if it is possible to terminal into my Android (Razr) and navigate the file system and processes like you would on any other Linux distribution.  As it is supposed to be built on top of the Linux Kernel.

I find it annoying that you simply can't shut down most apps, like Firefox for example, from the phone's default UI, I wish there would be a way to find the process ID and kill it like you would on a regular Linux/Unix machine.

Comment: By "default UI" you mean something other than the application manager, from where you can terminate apps? (Or any of the process manager apps?)

Comment: yes, it can be done like that and i have but forgot it.  you are right.  but shutting down an app is just one example.  there are many more why i would like to have shell access.  one would be, for example to do find/grep.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you enable debugging and have the Android SDK installed then you can use `adb shell` to get a shell on the android device using the USB cable to a PC. If you want something just on the device, ConnectBot which is a SSH client application that is available for free, can provide a localhost only shell which will let you work as for most linux systems. Note that the shell is fairly restricted. A lot of common commands are missing.

Answer (score 3):

```
adb shell
```

with your phone connected to your PC, via network or USB according to your device, with *USB debug* enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I use the connectbot app; it's primarily useful as an ssh client but also allows you to run a local terminal session